# Difference between nullify(pointer) and pointer => null()

Tags: pointers, null, fortran

What is the difference between

```
procedure(some_routine), pointer :: ptr
ptr => null()
```

and

```
procedure(some_routine), pointer :: ptr
nullify(ptr)
```

Does nullify do something behind the scenes? Or is it just two different ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result is completely identical. The assignment sign `=>` can be also used for variable initialization or derived type components default initialization, where the `nullify` statement is unusable, but that is only a syntactic thing, it is not a proper assignment in fact.

For example

```
  type t
    real, pointer :: ptr => null()
  end type
```

is the default initialization of a component, and

```
 program p
   real, pointer :: ptr2 => null()
```

is initialization of a variable. The variable `ptr2` is implicitly `save` as any other initialized variable (a common source of errors).

Comment: But please be aware of the implicit `save` when combining declaration and initialization!

Comment: I took that into account in the answer now.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the variable assignment, actually, we often use it that way, but was unsure if it is the way of choice. Especially mixing both looked kind of fishy to me. But as it both is the same, there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: It is completely the same. For the two types initializations I showed as an addition be aware they are Fortran 95 and not 90.